# Switching Action Bar Menu

Tags: android, android-webview, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I am trying to show different menus in actionbar (I'm using the sherlock action bar), depending on the javascript function that performs open page in webview.

For example, in page1.html, `Android.showMenu(1)` is called.
While in page2.html, `Android.ShowMenuB(2)` is called.

Currently the menu is all defined by the java code, like this:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {
super.onCreateOptionsMenu (menu);
MenuItem menu0 menu.add = (0, 0, 0, "ButtonA");
{
menu0.setIcon (R.drawable.buttona);
menu0.setShowAsAction (MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
}
MenuItem menu1 menu.add = (0, 1, 1, "ButtonB");
{
menu1.setIcon (R.drawable.buttonb);
menu1.setShowAsAction (MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
}
return true;
}
```

I'm detecting the presence of the functions using the JavascriptInterface this way:

```
myWebView.addJavascriptInterface (new WebAppInterface (this), "Android");
...
{public class WebAppInterface
Context mContext;
WebAppInterface (Context c) {
mContext = c;
}
@ JavascriptInterface
public void showMenuA (int menu) {
??
}
}
```

Is it possible? Or will I have to use other methods?

Comment: I am also struggling in the same screnario. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` to populate action items on the fly and invalidate the action bar using `invalidateOptionsMenu()`

Comment: Hi, I am also struggling in the above scenario.Could you please give me the code? How can I add dynamically menu items and give a callback to the javascript while clicking the menu item.?